# Dynamically position a DIV over specific text

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-size

I am displaying a long, contiguous fragment of text (representing DNA sequence) on a single line in a web page.  I'm using a mono-width font and would like to use javascript to dynamically position a DIV at a certain character in the text (say at the 20th character, 50th character, etc).  What's the best way to calculate coordinates that I could use to position the DIV?  I need the solution to be robust to the user changing font size in their browser.

Edited:

I added a jsfiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/kQLqV/ and added the code below.

In the example, I'd like to be able to position the blue box over the 10th-20th letters, for example.  I want to be able to do this dynamically in the javascript so that I could move the box to different locations in the text.  I did think about putting each letter in a span, but given that there could be ~1000 letters, the overhead seemed high for something that seems like it *should* be trivial.

```
<style>
.sequence {
  font-family: Courier;
  font-size:12px;
  width: 70%;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

<div id="my_seq" class="sequence">CAGCATCAGCATACGACTACGACGACTCAGCGACTACAGCATACGACGGGSCAAGGTACTGATCATAAATGCATAGACGATAAGACATAGAACGATAAGAGATTACGA...</div>

<script>
$("#my_seq").append("<div style='position:absolute; min-height: 100%; background-color:rgba(30,144,255,0.3); top:0; left:20px; width: 200px;'> </div>");
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: can you include some code? It would help us better for your specific situation. I'm having trouble visualizing what exactly you want. So you want a div that follows characters within another div?

Comment: Including some sample code would be very much helpful, really  :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid doing the math on characters and font extents.  Instead, make the strings up out of single character spans and then you can get the element size and positioning using offsetWidth and offsetLeft (also Height and Top if needed) on the span objects.

This approach will have some overhead so if you can merge spans that should help.